# How to write measure in DAX to sum value for two particular warehouse codes in the same column

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

Need help in adding the values for two warehouse codes in same column.

Please find the input data in image link:

```
Warehouse  Stock
GH         6
NSWA       10
NSWA-SW    20
NSWA-01    5
QLDA       15
QLDA-SW    30
GSWG       40
WASA       10
WASA-SW    4
WASA-07    11
```

My input data has two columns. Warehouse and Stock.
EX: NSWA is a main warehouse and NSWA-SW is sub warehouse and all other warehouse codes are small branches.
My goal is to sum the stock for all the warehouse codes ending with -SW (sub warehouse NSWA-SW ) and its respective main warehouse (NSWA). My measure should ignore all other warehouse codes.

Please find the output image link below

```
Warehouse  Stock
GH       
NSWA     
NSWA-SW    30 (sum of NSWA and NSWA-SW)
NSWA-01  
QLDA     
QLDA-SW    45 (sum of QLDA and QLDA-SW)
GSWG     
WASA     
WASA-SW    14 (sum of WASA and WASA-SW)
WASA-07
```

I could only get the value for the warehouse codes ending with -SW using calculate and filter warehouse code by Right 3 characters.

My Dax Query:

```
SW Warehouse = Calculate(sum(stock),
                        filter(warehouse, right([warehouse code],3) = "-SW"))
```

I need the logic how to match the -sw warehouse codes with the respective main branch.

Answer (score 0):

I created a variable MainWarehouse to the main warehouse code by stripping off the "-SW" from any sub-warehouse codes.
If the warehouse code doesn't end in "-SW", it's assumed to be a main warehouse, and the code is used as-is.

```
Adjusted Stock = 
VAR MainWarehouse = 
    IF(
        RIGHT([Warehouse], 3) = "-SW", 
        LEFT([Warehouse], LEN([Warehouse]) - 3), 
        [Warehouse]
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        SUM([Stock]),
        FILTER(
            ALL('MyTable'),
            [Warehouse] = MainWarehouse ||
            [Warehouse] = MainWarehouse & "-SW"
        )
    )
```

[image]